# Using a Bootstrap Theme with Webpack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have a web application that uses Bootstrap 3. I'm using webpack, so I `npm installed`ed bootstrap, and I'm referencing it like so:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

This works well. But now I want to use a different bootstrap theme ([Slate](https://bootswatch.com/slate/)), that only changes the css file.

I can think of two options of doing this.

1. Replace bootstrap.css inside the `node_modules` directory. Since `node_modules` is not a part of our source repo, we will need to do this repeatedly. This is clearly not a good option.
2. Don't use npm for bootstrap at all - put all the bootstrap files in a folder and reference that instead. This will work, but we won't get updates if a new version of Bootstrap is released.

Is there a way to reference bootstrap.css from one place, and all the other bootstrap files from another place? Can webpack do that?

Comment: You could potentially use [Webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to override the resolution of `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` with a local copy of the theme, I think? Bit hacky, but I think that would allow you to keep using all the other stuff from the package. I make no promises, though :p

Comment: Have you tried [bootstrap-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader)?

Comment: Take look at [bootstrap loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader).